# i want to have the highest number of town_city each year MYsql

Tags: php, mysql

i have these on my data base

year   | city
2011  | new york
2010   | LA 
2010   | LA 
2010   | new york 
2012   | texas

i have a 2 column contains named year and town_city

and i want to have the highest number of town_city each year .

outout should be

year | city       | total  
2011 | new york    |  1
2010 | LA |  2 
2012 | texas | 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can get your desired result using this:

```
SELECT year, city, count(*)
FROM city_table ct1
WHERE year=(SELECT max(year) FROM city_table ct2 WHERE ct2.city=ct1.city)
GROUP BY year, city
```

Comment: thnx man. that is helpful by i need only the highest every year. 1 for 2010 , 2011, 2012

Comment: SELECT year, city, count(*)
FROM city_table ct1
WHERE year=(SELECT max(year) FROM city_table ct2 WHERE ct2.city=ct1.city)
GROUP BY year


got it now. tnx

Comment: that only shows the max year. and subquery doest return more than one row.

Comment: I thought that's exactly what you're asking for - the highest year for each city.  On your given example, this query gives exactly the results you indicated you want.

Comment: oh sorry my bad. yes but it show only the maximum year on the database.

Comment: i need to have all the distinct years with the highest number of cities. 

sory my english is rubbish.

Comment: @ChadwickNagka-GahiComeros: in that case, the expected result you're showing in your question is totally wrong.  Update your answer with what you expect to see.

Answer (score 1):

A few steps to do this:

First - you'll want to find all distinct names:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT column_name(s)
  FROM table_name
```

This will produce an array that includes New York, LA, Texas - save this as $unique;

Secondly, step through your array, running a SQL query with that specific value, saving the resulting number as a multidimensional array:

```
  foreach ($unique as Su):
   $u[$i['city'] = $u;
   $u[$i]['num'] =
  //SQL COUNT

   SELECT COUNT(city) AS City FROM TableName
   WHERE City=$u        
   FROM table_name 

 //increase array count
    $i++; 
 endforeach;
```

This will leave you with an array something like:

```
     $u[0]['city'] = New York
     $u[0]['num'] = 2
```

Comment: the SU in  ($unique as Su) is this should be $u? sorry im new to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT year, city, count(*)
FROM city_table
GROUP by year, city;
```

Comment: it gets the total number of city but i need only the highest every eary and take note that i have repeating values on the year column
tnx

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use this query:

```
SELECT year,city,count(*) AS total FROM tablename group by city;
```

group by will only return rows that have a unique city, while the count will show you how many rows were combine.

Comment: it gets the total number of city but i need only the highest every eary and take note that i have repeating values on the year column
tnx